# Ropey old recordings of radio broadcasts about the Vietnam war?

Tags: design, recordings

Hey everyone,

I've searched YouTube etc but was wondering if there's some kind of old historical database where old radio reports would be stored?

The quality really doesn't matter - in fact the more old and ropey , the better!

Anyone know of such a place? Reports about troops progress in the war - be it news presenters talking about western soldiers being killed or even new advances made.

I'm a bit stuck and would prefer real authentic bits of news rather than ADR'ing fake ones and adding crusty old recording sounds on top! Would really need about 3 different incidents. I've got propaganda sounds for the war off of archive.org - but half way through the short piece I want to then play some recordings of how it ACTUALLY went.
Any help or links would be brilliant!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh ho, I found a few more that might be of interest to people in future if they're making backgrounds for war drama's.

http://archive.org/details/TheArmyAirMobilityTeam

http://ia600202.us.archive.org/17/items/Know_Your_Enemy-The_Vietcong/Know_Your_Enemy-The_Vietcong.mpg

Hope this helps someone in future :)

Comment: Hate to break it to you but after having read the terms of service, anything on that website is for educational, non-commercial use only.  Unfortunate, but those are the rules.  It is a thing to be careful of in general - just because something is old/archived doesn't mean it's public domain or rights are freely available.

Answer (score 0):

As i type this i'm digitally tracking about 3hrs of audio from an American Vietnam Radio Station. If you would like a copy Email me at cole.rippe@me.com

"And the hits just keep on coming!"

Authentic, Explicit and **AWESOME**!